# Pass Variable to Register Sidebar?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to pass a variable containing an image url into an array for use in my WordPress theme.

I want it to be dynamic, so I've stored the html in a variable, but I can't figure out why I cannot pass it into my $args array.

Is this possible?

```
// Build a path to image
$path_start = '<img src="';
$site = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
$path_end = '/img/hr.png" class="hr">';

// Join it together
$full = $path_start . $site . $path_end;

// Pass it into Sidebar
function custom_sidebars() {
$args = array(
'id'            => 'applause-1',
'name'          => 'Applause 1',
'description'   => 'Main sidebar, above a horizontal rule',
'before_widget' => '',
'after_widget'  => $full,
'before_title'  => '',
'after_title'   => ''
);

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I defined my variables OUTSIDE the scope of my function in my previous example.

Fixed code:

```
function custom_sidebars() {

// Build a path to image
$path_start = '<img src="';
$site = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
$path_end = '/img/hr.png" class="hr">';

// Join it together
$full = $path_start . $site . $path_end;

$args = array(
'id'            => 'applause-1',
'name'          => 'Applause 1',
'description'   => 'Main sidebar, above a horizontal rule',
'before_widget' => '',
'after_widget'  => $full,
'before_title'  => '',
'after_title'   => ''
);
```

Comment: it is `INSIDE` the function. and you can also use , make `global $full`.